# Algebraic content of Gauss's Theorema Egregium

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

Let me first recall what Gauss's Theorema Egregium says.  Consider a surface isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  In some local coordinates, let the first and second fundamental forms be
$$E \text{dx}^2 + 2F \text{dx} \text{dy} + G \text{dy}^2$$
and
$$L \text{dx}^2 + 2M \text{dx} \text{dy} + N \text{dy}^2.$$
The Gaussian curvature is
$$K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}.$$
Gauss's theorem says that despite this formula, $K$ only depends on the first fundamental form.

The proof of this basically algebraic, and comes down to some remarkable formulas (the Gauss Equations) arising from the equality of iterated mixed partial derivatives.

**Question**: What is the right algebraic setting for this?  The only relationships between the first and second fundamental forms are the Codazzi–Mainardi equations, so it must be that somehow these equations force $K$ to be independent of the second fundamental form.  These equations involve some partial derivatives, but given that no real analysis goes into Gauss's theorem I assume there must be a more general algebraic setting for this sort of result (but I have no idea what buzzwords to search for).

Comment: There's many appealing settings for the proof, so perhaps the "right" setting is whatever you like the most.  For me, one of the most appealing proofs is the one where you see curvature coming up in the Taylor expansion of geodesic normal coordinates.  In some sense, you could think of this as a variational principle, or if you are more reductionist, it comes down to Clairault's Theorem i.e. mixed partials being equal.

Comment: The proof I perhaps like a little more is the one where you express the Taylor expansion of the holonomy around a small loop as a power series, with the first non-trivial term being the curvature tensor.  At its heart it has the key idea for the proof of Gauss-Bonnet as well.

Comment: Since Gauss+Codazzi-Mainardi can be seen as integrability conditions (Frobenius type -thus in terms of Lie brackets) of a distribution given rise to the surface having prescibed 1st and 2nd fundamental form I guess that one could show in a purely algebraic manner that when you have a pos.def. symmetric matrix G and a symmetric matrix L satisfy the compatibility conditions then $det L$ depends only on elements of $G$. I haven't ventured into making this explicit though.

Comment: If you like the notion of connection, you can prove that the Levi-Civita connection depends only on the metric, and then that the Gauss curvature is the curvature of the Levi-Civita connection. Clearly all steps are algebraic, and you can count derivatives to see that the algebra is on the 2-jet bundle of metrics.

Comment: Good question! This is a good example of why I dislike using $E, F, G, L, M, N$ to denote the coefficients of the metric tensor and second fundamental form. As you suspect, the proof is indeed algebraic. It follows from tensor algebraic identities. This is more easily seen when doing the proof in $n$ dimensions and using coefficients with indices to represent a tensor with respect to local coordinates. I have two short notes that might address your question using minimal machinery (specifically, I avoid mention of the Levi-Civita connection and Christoffel symbols).

Comment: The core fact that drives all of this is that partial derivatives commute. The two notes are: https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/riemann.pdf and https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/gauss.pdf. The notes are pretty terse, so feel free to post questions or email me. I would add that in these notes, the definition of Gauss curvature arises naturally from the calculation and does not need to be stated in advance. So it provides a plausible way it was originally discovered.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I know how to compute the Taylor expansion of geodesic normal coordinates, but the proof I know relies on already having an intrinsic formula for the Gaussian curvature (so this does not provide a proof of Gauss's theorem).  Do you know a source that avoids this?

Comment: @DeaneYang: That's a very attractive way of presenting the argument!  I'll think about it, and might follow up with some questions.

Comment: I think what @RyanBudney has in mind is basically what is in my note about Riemann curvature. You don’t need to define curvature to define and construct geodesic normal coordinates. Since they’re uniquely defined, the second order term is a well defined tensor and is the Riemann curvature tensor. The only thing new in my note is that I point out that you don’t need geodesic normal coordinates for this argument.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I'll look at your note, but maybe the following basic fact will clarify what the issue is.  I'll stick to dimension 2 and expand things out in geodesic polar coordinates around a point $p$.  The metric is then $dr^2+G d\theta^2$ for some function $G(r,\theta)$, and the curvature is $K = -\sqrt{G}_{rr}/\sqrt{G}$.  It's easy enough to work out that as $r \mapsto 0$ the function $\sqrt{G}$ approaches $0$ and $(\sqrt{G})_r$ approaches $1$.  The deeper fact is that $(\sqrt{G})_{rr}$ approaches $0$ and $(\sqrt{G})_{rrr}$ approaches $-K(p)$, and in particular that these

Comment: limits are independent of the angle.  I believe that the higher derivatives approach limits that do depend on the angle (depending e.g. on the directional derivatives of $K$ at $p$).  I don't know how to prove these without knowing that the above expression for $K$ comes from a smooth function on the surface (and in particular one that is smooth at $p$), which at least to me is not obvious without having first proven some version of Gauss's theorem.  Just to be clear, I want to understand $\sqrt{G}$ to get asymptotics on lengths of things like geodesic circles.

Comment: I have always found doing calculations in polar coordinates confusing, especially if I want to establish regularity at the origin. So what I always do is do the calculation in Cartesian coordinates and convert the final answer into polar coordinates if needed. If you want to calculate the higher derivatives of the metric in geodesic normal coordinates, the easiest way I know to do this is to use Jacobi fields. This is an easy way to get explicit formulas for the higher derivatives of $g$ evaluated at the origin in terms of the covariant derivatives of the curvature tensor.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Thanks!

Comment: @Tara: Reading over this, I realized that you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of the situation. You wrote, *The only relationships between the first and second fundamental forms are the Codazzi–Mainardi equations, so it must be that somehow these equations force $K$ to be independent of the second fundamental form.*  $$ $$ However, this is *not* true. The C-M equations alone do *not* force the Gauss equation, i.e., $K = (LN-M^2)/(EG-F^2)$.This is a separate equation, independent of C-M; after all, since the C-M are linear in $L,M,N$, they are satisfied by $L=M=N=0$ even when $K\not=0$.